# I want to replace a name in auth.tsx

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a field in auth.tsx, I want to replace that value

```
Linking.openURL("https://apps.apple.com/in/app/demo/id657");
```

I want to replace "demo" with "test"

```
Linking.openURL("https://apps.apple.com/in/app/test/id657");
```

I tried using `sed` command

```
sed -i 's/demo/test/g' auth.tsx
```

it's working but, it replaces all the other "demo" value with "test".

I need to replace the "demo" value in this place only

```
 Linking.openURL("https://apps.apple.com/in/app/demo/id657");
```

Comment: Just use the full sentence instead of a part of it. Assuming this sentence is a full line: `sed -i 's!^sentence$!sentence-with-demo!' auth.tsx`. (use `!` as separator instead of the default `/` that is part of the sentence).

Comment: For the future, before posting a question, I suggest you to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We needed a more significant part of the file `auth.tsx` in this case.

Comment: Unless you give more details and an explanation of why you want to use a command to do the replacement instead of a text editor, you can get joke answers that are technically valid: Ex. search string is the entire content of the file, and the replacement is the entire content you want to have afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you only want to make the change for the line containing v.gr. `id657`, you could issue:

```
sed -i '/id657/s/demo/test/' auth.tsx
```

Since there is only one occurence of `demo` to be changed, the `g` at the end of the `sed` command makes no sense.

Adapt this command in function of the condition for selecting the right occurence to be changed.